# How do i filter array of objects nested in property of array objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have model like this:

`var model = [{id: 1, prices: [{count: 2}, {count: 3}]}, {id: 2, prices: [{count: 2}]}, {id: 3, prices: [{count: 3}]}];`

and I need to filter this objects of array useing property `count` and I will need to return matched objects in three scenarios:

1. if the objects have two objects in array `prices`,
2. if the objects have one object in array `prices` matching `count:2`,
3. if the objects have one property in array `prices` matching `count:3`.

so..when i click the button without assigned value i wanna see all objects, when i click button with value = 2 i wanna see objects with count: 2 and when i click the button with value = 3 i wanna get objects with count: 3, i must do this in AngularJS –

Comment: write a function to perform these calculations against the model data and return a new model, then run this function whenever you load the model data.  use the new model for your display.

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter to loop through the model array, perform the checks on the prices array and then if it matches any of those conditions return it.

Comment: Please edit your question to be specific, and also what you're actually stuck on. Are you confused about how to use Array.filter, or how to write logic in JS? Or how to set up the UI in Angular?

Comment: Andy Ray i have proble with every issues which u call..

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
var result = model.filter(function(m) {
   // make sure the m.prices field exists and is an array
   if (!m.prices || !Array.isArray(m.prices)) {
       return false;
   }

   var numOfPrices = m.prices.length

   if (numOfPrices === 2) { // return true if its length is 2
       return true;
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < numOfPrices; i++) {
       if (m.prices[i].count && 
           (m.prices[i].count === 2 || 
            m.prices[i].count == 3)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use lodash or underscore library.. and then your code with lodash will be like:

```
_.filter(model, function(i){
   return _.intersection(_.map(i.prices, 'count'), [3,2]).length;
})
```

it returns items that on their price property have array which contains element with count = 3 or count = 2

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = [{
    id: 1,
    prices: [{
        count: 2
    }, {
        count: 3
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    prices: [{
        count: 2
    }]
}, {
    id: 3,
    prices: [{
        count: 3
    }]
}];

var search = function(data) {
    var result = {};

    function arrayObjectIndexOf(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
        for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    for (var index in data) {
        if (data[index].hasOwnProperty("prices") && arrayObjectIndexOf(data[index].prices, 2, 'count') != -1) {
            result[data[index].id] = data[index];
        } else if (data[index].hasOwnProperty("prices") && arrayObjectIndexOf(data[index].prices, 3, 'count') != -1) {
            result[data[index].id] = data[index];
        } else if (data[index].hasOwnProperty("prices") &&
            data[index].prices.length == 2) {
            result[data[index].id] = data[index];
        }

    }

    return result;
}
var output = search(model);
console.log(output);
```